# Is the multiplier of the primal problem equal to the solution of the dual problem if strong duality holds and the solution of primal is unique?

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems

Assume we meet this problem:
$$
\min_x f(x)\\
s.t. g(x)=0, h(x)\leq 0
$$
Let's assume the solution is $(x^*,\nu^*,\lambda^*)$

Its dual problem is
$$
\max_{\nu,\lambda} l(\nu,\lambda)\\
s.t. \lambda\geq 0
$$
where $l(v,\lambda)=\min_xf(x)+\nu g(x)+\lambda h(x)$. The solution is $\nu^{**},\lambda^{**}$.

Can we prove $\nu^*=\nu^{**}$ and $\lambda^*=\lambda^{**}$ with strong duality and also $(x^*,\nu^*,\lambda^*)$ being unique, or is it wrong? Of course, if you can prove this with only strong duality, it would be better.

Thank you for finishing reading this. I appreciate it.